# How to get Get Rendering usercontrol path i.e Ascx file using Rendering ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, content-management-system, sitecore

I need to get `.ascx` user control file system paths from the `RenderingID`.
The below code gives me the list of renderings of an item but it doesn't return the path of the user control in any of the properties of `RenderingReference` data object.

```cs
public RenderingReference[] GetListOfSublayouts(Sitecore.Data.ID itemId)
{
    Sitecore.Layouts.RenderingReference[] renderings = null;

    Item item = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(Sitecore.Data.ID.Parse(itemId));
    if (item != null)
    {
        renderings = item.Visualization.GetRenderings(Sitecore.Context.Device, true);
    }

    return renderings;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `RenderingReference` object has `RenderingItem` property.
2. `RenderingItem` has `InnerItem` property.
3. `InnerItem` is of the `Item` type and it's the sublayout item in Sitecore tree. It has `Path` field which contains path to the ascx file.

So the code will be something like this:

```cs
RenderingReference firstReference = renderings[0];
RenderingItem renderingItem = firstReference.RenderingItem;
Item innerItem = renderingItem.InnerItem;
string ascxPath = innerItem["Path"];
```

This code is NOT tested but should point you in the right direction.

You should add null checks and test the templates (e.g. if the innerItem is using `/sitecore/templates/System/Layout/Renderings/Sublayout` template).